# C++ truncate double

Tags: c++, rounding, truncate, truncation

There is variable **amount** of double type with value **269.80000000000001**

I need truncate it to 2 decimals.

```
double result1 = round(amount * 100) / 100;
double result2 = (double)trunc(amount * 100) / 100;
```

after that
**result1** and **result2** is still equals **269.80000000000001**

Please tell me how truncate it to 2 decimals and why methods above does not work?

Comment: 269.8 is not representable by `double`: http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_double.html?decimal=050054057046056

Comment: Try to represent `0.8` as the sum of negative powers of `2` (`0.5`, `0.25`, `0.125`, etc).   You'll find it is an infinite series, in exactly the same way that `1/3` is an infinite series in decimal (`0.3333.....`).  That is the reason that typical floating point types cannot exactly represent a value like `0.8`.   Or `269.8`.  They only represent an approximation, as you are seeing.

Comment: it doesnt matter that you did these operations, the result is still stored to a double variable. They would have to be displayed till the required precision regardless., try storing the result to a float variable .

Comment: Out of interest, why do you need it truncated?

Comment: Don't store amounts in floating point variables. Instead store it in integer in minor units and do calculations on those

Comment: Just print it to two decimal places to get output of `269.80`.   That doesn't change the value to be equal to `296.8`.   It simply displays it in way that (arguably) better suits a human.

Comment: Made calculations without truncation. 
And format rounding at output std::ostringstream streamConvertor;
streamConvertor << std::setprecision(2) << std::fixed << value;